# SMJobRemove succeeds, but plist and helper tool not deleted

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, launchd

I'm trying to remove a privileged helper tool installed via `SMJobBless`, I'm getting a positive return value and no errors, yet the files at /Library/PrivilegedTools and /Library/LaunchDaemons are not deleted. Do I have to delete these files myself?

From the documentation I read:

> Return Value true if the job was removed successfully, otherwise
>   false.

I'm calling the following to remove the job:
`result = SMJobRemove(kSMDomainSystemLaunchd, (__bridge CFStringRef)label, _authRef, YES, &errorCF);`

Comment: Any luck? I'm in the same boat.

Comment: This question is related. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699992/can-smjobsubmit-be-used-to-execute-a-privileged-helper-installed-by-smjobbless/11822408#comment16953899_11822408 The blog post attached to it, http://www.stairways.com/blog/2012-08-06-smjobsubmit might also have some leads.

Comment: Unfortunately I have not yet found anything regarding smjobremove not physically removing the files. If anyone knows a direct answer that would be great :)

Comment: See this [Apple Dev Forums thread](https://devforums.apple.com/message/732683#732683) (developer account required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks **jatoben**, that thread had the answer I was looking for.

As suspected you do have to remove the files yourself or use the following: (Taken from Apple dev forums:)

> SMJobRemove is the equivalent of "launchctl remove".  That is, it
>   removes the job from launchd but has no effect on the disk at all. 
>   Thus the job will get reloaded the next time you start up.  To get
>   around that you have to either remove the plist yourself or by
>   fork/exec'ing "launchctl unload -w".

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen https://github.com/brenwell/SMJobBless-Demo/blob/master/Uninstall.sh? It was very helpful for me.