# Correct usage of SMJobBless for single action?

Tags: macos, cocoa, security, service-management

I'm running a little tool to run an action that has a start and end (it's an installer). I don't want to leave things lying around the filesystem (or the launchd config) after the installer runs. If it ever runs again it can re-blessed etc.

Is this the right approach to take for jobs that will only run once?

(also if you're knowledgable, take a look at [11557026](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557026/smjobremove-succeeds-but-plist-and-helper-tool-not-deleted), it needs an answer!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was no, SMJobSubmit is the right thing to use, as per this question: [Can SMJobSubmit() be used to execute a privileged helper installed by SMJobBless?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699992/can-smjobsubmit-be-used-to-execute-a-privileged-helper-installed-by-smjobbless/11822408#comment16953899_11822408)